# Getting rid of errors from using arrays as constants

Tags: phpstorm

So, as you may know, in PHP 5.6+, you can use arrays as constants. e.g.:

```
const MEMBER_TYPES = array("User", "Moderator", "Admin");
```

However, in my PHPStorm installation, I get an error when doing this, even though when running the code I get no errors at all, using PHP 5.6.8. None of the inspections I'm seeing via Alt+Enter are doing anything.. is there a way to suppress this specific error detection?

Comment: while you are waiting for the bugfix, you can: assign the constant to a new variable $newVar = MyClass::CONST_NAME;  echo $newVar['key_name'];

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not yet supported by PhpStorm

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26366 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 0):

Reported as fixed in 10.0.2 by PhpStorm folks. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26366#comment=27-1257245